# How do you make AutoLayout make UIimageviews bigger according to screen size?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

So I have an app I'm working on, but I hit a major problem. In this app we have several images. I'm learning AutoLayout, and I can make stuff appear the same on all device screens, except for the fact that the images (and for that matter, everything) remain the same size. I want them to get bigger and smaller according to screen size. I've tried everything I know. Help!

Comment: What constraints have you set?  If you set width/height constraints then the sizes will be fixed. You should set leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints so that the space to the edges is fixed and the size of the images changes

Comment: One app I'm working on I'm using both. I have a stack view next to some buttons. The stack view expands nicely, but I can't get the buttons to expand. The stack view has all the leading/trailing constraints, and for now the buttons have set width/height. I've tried to do what I did for the stack view for the buttons, but for some reason they don't seem to work. They don't size out equally. The buttons are supposed to be squares but they change shape and they aren't all the same size/shape (rectangles or squares).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use propotional width and height to the superView. At first Ctrl drag from your `imageView` to `superView` and set [Equal Height and Equal Width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52SpP.png). And now set the Propotional height and width to the `superView` from the [constraint list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjhjw.png). Here you can set your height and width with Propotional to `superView` with Multiplier option. And finally set your x and y position of your image [Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txvSm.png). Here I have used `horizontaly` and `verticaly` centered.

Answer (score 0):

Using the image here as an example:

[image]

First, place your imageview where you would like it, in terms of how far it should be from borders of the view or other objects.

Then, click on the small tie-fighter like icon in the bottom to bring up the add new constraints window.

From there, click on the four links show in red inside the red box. These tell XCode that it should be "80 units from the left most object, 80 units from the right most, etc".

Now, when you change to different devices, it will always adhere to those standards.

However, depending upon the size you selected, it may not work under certain conditions such as being rotated to landscape, or in a split view on an iPad. This is where you get into the other size classes, which you access by clicking the text at the bottom of XCode that says "w Any h Any".

One item of note, do not select the image size in width or height in the constraints window seen below. Doing so will constrain the image size, invalidating the margins put in place.

Comment: Is it possible to build the whole storyboard in Any/Any? This particular app is always landscape. Or do you set out most everything in Any/Any but you do have to change size classes for some constraints?

Comment: It depends on how you want to layout the app. There is nothing that prevents you from using Any/Any together with storyboard, but you may be limited in placing items based upon your design. One recent example is that I made an app that is almost exclusively table views, with some simple label/image screens, and everything was done successfully in Any/Any for both portrait & landscape.